# How to listen for changes in prop state in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am porting over a Backbone.View into React. I might be missing something, but I cannot figure out the idiomatic way to make the state of a component dependent on the states of their sibling. For example, say that I have a component like this:

```
<Timeline>
  <Page selected="true" onClick={this.handleClick} />
  <Page selected="false" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
</Timeline>
```

And let's say all handleClick does it to `setState({selected: true})`. My question is how do I make sure that the state of the siblings of this component are set to false before it is set to true.

My ideal solution would be to listen for changes in prop state and forceRender the sub-components from the Timeline component, but I don't know if this is an accepted approach.

I am also looking for alternative ways to implement this component, since I understand the [recommended way to decompose the components](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-components-should-have-state) is to keep them as stateless as possible to ensure they can be reused elsewhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In cases where siblings seem to have interdependent state, you'll want to hoist up the relevant pieces of state up to the parent component.

In this case, you probably want to store `selectedPage` on the parent's state object, causing the render method to look like

```
<Timeline>
  <Page selected={this.state.selectedPage === 1} onClick={this.handleClick} />
  <Page selected={this.state.selectedPage === 2} onClick={this.handleClick} />
</Timeline>
```

or similar. When you want to change the selected page, simply change the `selectedPage` value stored on the parent, possibly from within a callback passed to the children.

By following this pattern, you can ensure that the two pages are always in sync with each other -- each time the parent rerenders the props will be updated simultaneously on the two children.

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the difference between this.state and this.props? I see them both used for similar things. In what context is state more appropriate than props, and vice versa?

Comment: @picardo That is a good question, but you should post a new topic about it.

Comment: @picardo Pete Hunt's blog post includes a section called "[Identify where your state should live](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live)" that explains props vs. state well.

Comment: Yes, that blog post is great.

Comment: Yeah - ***That blog post is great*** !

Comment: Ben, does change in parent's state cause render in children to redraw elements?